# How to fill Panel with Buttons of the equal size

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Panel`, inside the `Panel` are two or more(in the future) buttons.

How to make those buttons fully fill the `Panel` and have the same size **independently** of the `Panel` size changes during the application run?

**EDIT**: According to answers which talk about resize event. The problem is that when the next button is added it won't automatically resize rest of the buttons. Also, as far as I understand this resizing would happen ONLY when the `Panel` is resized and first I have to carefully set the size of the buttons in the Designer. The ideal solution would work like Java's `GridLayout` -> no worries about the size of any button.

[image]

Comment: You want them resize to keep the panel always filled with buttons of the same size?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Yes, that's right. But in the future there will be 3 buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rely on `SizeChanged` event of the panel to get what you want. Sample code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     panel1.SizeChanged += panel1_SizeChanged;

 }

 private void panel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     resizeButtons();
 }

 private void resizeButtons()
 {
     int totButtons = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().Count();

     Point curPos = new Point(0, 0);
     foreach(Button but in panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
     {
         but.Width = panel1.Width / totButtons; 
         but.Location = curPos;
         curPos = new Point(curPos.X + but.Width, 0);
     }
 }
```

This code makes sure that any number of buttons fill all the horizontal space no matter how much the size of `Panel1` changes.

Comment: But when the Panel will not change its' size it won't work? And when I add 3rd button I need to divide by 3? I look for sth similar to that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: @Yoda Sorry I thought that you meant just 2 button. Will come back in brief.

Comment: @Yoda The updated code takes care of the horizontal resizing. Do you want also the vertical space? You have to set further constratints, like minimum with of buttons.

Comment: Works great. The only last question. Dies `Resize Event` also occures when drawing the `Panel` for the first time(altough the size stayed original)?

Comment: @Yoda It depends. It is called in my code because I set .Dock = DockStyle.Fill; (or if you change the size on the Form Load); otherwise is not called. But you can call the function directly.

Comment: Instead of a panel you can use ,You can use a TableLayoutPanel, it automatically manages the size and position of controls

Comment: @AitYahiaIdir thanks for the tip but I am not the one interested in this; I have just given a solution for the requested problem. You should write this kind of comments to the OP (in his question, where he can read them).

Comment: @varocarbas i am sorry, the comment is intended to Yoda, your snippet still a good solution